# Jade - how to denote an attribute with a hyphen?

Tags: node.js, pug

I would like to place an html5 `data-attribute` on a tag in a jade template.  How on earth do I do this? The following gives a syntax error.

```
 script(data-main="public/javascripts" src="public/javascripts/require.js")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct, but you need a comma between the attributes.

```
script(data-main="public/javascripts", src="public/javascripts/require.js")
```

Comment: oh...oh duh. That's what I get for copy pasting